# multer upload image without form using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multer

I'm actually using this working multer code to upload file.
But I would like to use ng-click() to send more things from my controller with $http post. A simple input with a button will be the best.

html side:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/productimage">
      <p>
        <input type="file" id="imgadd" name="upl"/>
      </p>
      <p>
         <input type="submit"/> 
      </p>
</form>
```

server side:

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/products')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '.jpg') //Appending .jpg
  }
})

app.post('/productimage', multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: 200000} }).single('upl'), function(req,res, error){
    console.log(req.body); //form fields
    /* example output:
    { title: 'abc' }
     */
    console.log(req.file.filename); //form files
    /* example output:
            { fieldname: 'upl',
              originalname: 'grumpy.png',
              encoding: '7bit',
              mimetype: 'image/png',
              destination: './uploads/',
              filename: '436ec561793aa4dc475a88e84776b1b9',
              path: 'uploads/436ec561793aa4dc475a88e84776b1b9',
              size: 277056 }
     */
    res.status(204).end();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a directive as below

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
        function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChange = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            element.on('change', function (event) {
                onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
            });
        };
        return {
            link: fn_link
        }
    }])
```

then replace input type=file to

```
<input type="file" id="fileId" accept="image/*" file-model="myFiles($files)"/>
```

and then in your controller add this

```
var formData = new FormData();
$scope.myFiles = function($files) {
   formData.append('upl', $files[0]);
}
```

**Replace 'upl' to a name which you want it as in backend**
**if you want to Add something ,add each and every values with key & value pair in formData to send**
as

```
formData.append('name', form.name);
formData.append('title', form.title);
```

**Your image will be append directly but remember that data should be append on your function which is called by NG-CLICK **

Now your $http method

```
$http.post('/productimage', formData,{headers:{'Content-Type': undefined}}).then(...)
```

**After successful submission dont forget to delete formData as **
    formData.delete('name');

**Node Side**

```
app.post('/productimage', multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: 200000} }).single('upl'), function(req,res, error){
    console.log(req.body);
/*{title: 'xyz', name:'abc'}
*/ 
    console.log(req.file); 
    res.status(204).end();
});
```